# Cappuccino: NSTableView like component with collapsible rows?

Tags: cocoa, uikit, nstableview, cappuccino

I'm looking to build an NSTableView like widget in Cappuccino, but I'd like for each row to be able to expand, and almost have a subtree of child rows underneath it. In a sense, it's almost like a tree hierarchy UI widget, but displayed in a table like fashion with columns that are editable, etc.

I think there is a subclass to NSTableView that might be able to do this, but I can't think of the name. The idea is to keep the top level rows simple, with say, a Student's name. If you click on the down arrow of the student's name in that NSTableView row, a bunch of child information is displayed below it, such as Student's age, grades, classes, etc.

Is there a widget that can accommodate such a task in Cappuccino? What about in Cocoa/UIKit so we can look into a port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe CPOutlineView is the component you're looking for.